# What is the meaning of * in *ngFor in angular2?

Tags: angular

What is the meaning of * before ngFor in following sample and why it is needed?

```
<div *ngFor="#hero of heroes" (click)="selectHero(hero)">
  {{hero.name}}
</div>
```

Answer (score 37, accepted):

`ngFor` can only be applied to a `<template>`. `*ngFor` is the short form that can be applied to any element and the `<template>` element is created implicitly behind the scene.

https://angular.io/api/common/NgForOf

> Syntax
>
> - `<li *ngFor="let item of items; let i = index">...</li>`
> - `<li template="ngFor let item of items; let i = index">...</li>`
> - `<template ngFor let-item [ngForOf]="items" let-i="index"><li>...</li>`

It's the same pattern for all [structural directives](https://angular.io/guide/structural-directives)

[**Plunker example**](https://plnkr.co/edit/A5ttwA?p=preview)

**update**

With the 2.0.0 final release `<ng-container>` was introduced, that behaves like `<template>` (a wrapper element that isn't actually added to the DOM) but supports the `*ngFor="..."` syntax.

Comment: angular link for NgFor is dead

Comment: I'm only on the phone. You can search the API docs in http://angular.io for `ngfor` to get the correct link

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer, so by specifying the asterisk, I'm essentially saying that an angular should create a `template` element, correct?

Comment: Yes, that's basically what `*` means.

Answer (score 18):

When Angular sees the asterisk (*) in ngFor, it will use its DOM element as template to render the loop.

```
<div *ngFor="#hero of heroes">
  {{ hero.name }}
</div>
```

is equivalent to

```
<template ngFor #hero [ngForOf]="heroes">
    <div>
       {{ hero.name }}
    </div>
</template>
```

Comment: i'd love this answer if it were up to date with the syntax

Answer (score 8):

Quote from the official [Angular documentation](https://angular.io/api/common/NgForOf):

> When we reviewed the `NgFor` and `NgIf` built-in directives, we called out
>   an oddity of the syntax: the asterisk (*) that appears before the
>   directive name.
>
> The `*` is a bit of syntactic sugar that makes it easier to read and
>   write directives that modify HTML layout with the help of templates.
>   `NgFor`, `NgIf`, and `NgSwitch` all add and remove element subtrees that are
>   wrapped in `<template>` tags.

For more detail please check

https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#built-in-structural-directives

https://angular.io/guide/structural-directives#asterisk

*ngFor has four properties: *index*, *last*, *even*, and *odd*. We can get the value of index per iteration, the last value, odd, or even the index itself using local variables. Here is a working example:

```
demoArray= [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,8,9];
<ul>
  <li *ngFor='#item of demoArray #i=index #l=last #e=even'>
    Item value is : {{item}} has index value is : {{i}} and last value is :{{l}} even index :{{e}}</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 4):

They are known as Structural Directives, because they have ability to change the DOM Structure. 
For more information you can visit
https://angular.io/guide/structural-directives .

Answer (score 1):

In `*ngFor` the * is a shorthand for using the new angular template syntax with a template tag, this is also called structural Directive.It is helpful to know that * is just a shorthand to explicitly defining the data bindings on a template tag.