# Angular 5 White Screen

Tags: angular

I have made an update from Angular 2 to Angular 5.0.3, all packages are also installed and the program runs successfully. The problem is that I only see a white screen. With the development tool under console the following errors are displayed (see picture).
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kQIoA.png)

Can you please help me to solve this problem?

Many Thanks

Comment: Also please remove the angular5 tag and just use Angular. Angular 1 is called AngularJS now and Angular 2+ simply "Angular". That is the tag you are supposed to use.

Comment: you can edit your original post. you don't need to post an answer. Your code contains multiple problems. I can only give you the hint: no space between * and ngIf, *ngIf instead of gIf (typo) and use the notation `"ngFor let item of items; let i = index"` for `<template>`

Comment: And please accept my answer when you are finished. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

you are using the structural directive *ngFor in a wrong way; here is an example from tour of heroes:

```
<li *ngFor="let hero of heroes">
  {{ hero }}
</li>
```

see also: [What is the meaning of * in *ngFor in angular2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35498498/what-is-the-meaning-of-in-ngfor-in-angular2)

> ngFor (without star) can only be applied to a `<template>`. *ngFor is
>   the short form that can be applied to any element and the `<template>`
>   element is created implicitly behind the scene.
>
> https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/NgFor-directive.html

```
<li *ngFor="let item of items; let i = index">...</li>
<li template="ngFor let item of items; let i = index">...</li>
<template ngFor let-item [ngForOf]="items" let-i="index"><li>...</li>
```