# Print child values in JSON using ngFor

Tags: angular

I would like to display an accordion with parent child content using some JSON data that has Parent and Child properties.

When using `ngFor`, in app.component.html, it is printing only the first child property instead of all of them, when the accordion is expanded. Also, I would like the text box to have a unique id in each of the accordion panels.

[StackBlitz Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9p8y4i)

Comment: possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35498498/what-is-the-meaning-of-in-ngfor-in-angular2

Comment: This is not the issue with `ngFor`. All elements are properly rendered (but are not visible). Apart from the fact that you should not be manipulating DOM in angular, you're modifying `maxHeight` only of the first `.panel` inside toggled parent element.

Comment: Okay.. Thanks.. it makes sense. I will try to find another way to render the accordion.

Comment: Yes they are. [see screen](http://oi68.tinypic.com/302anuh.jpg) 
btw. these `hide` attributes are also useless

Comment: Please include all relevant code in a [mcve] here on Stack Overflow, not only on an external site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**CHECK** [**WORKING STACKBLITZ**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-accordion-demo-app)

Put the **`*ngFor` in your p tag instead of div**, it has the panel class which causes problems displaying the child items.

```
<div *ngFor="let item of data;let i = index;">
  <button class="accordion" (click)="toggleAccordian($event, i)"> {{item.parentName}} </button>
  <div class="panel" hide="!item.isActive">
    <input type="text">
    <p *ngFor="let child of item.childProperties"> {{child.propertyName}} </p>
  </div>
</div>
```